# Can 'Source' and 'Target' in the roads table for routing be duplicate?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing

I am using pgr_ksp for finding multiple paths for single source and destination. I am wondering if 'source' and 'target' in a roads table are unique or not. because when i am doing routing on my road network table and displaying their geometry on the basis of their 'target' value, it is giving me extra link roads everywhere. This is the query i am using

```
   SELECT pt.gid, seq AS route, id1 AS node,  id2 AS edge, cost, geom as line
   FROM pgr_ksp(
   'SELECT gid as id, source::int4, target::int4, length::float8 as cost FROM my_table',
    2087, 1428, 2, false
    )
    as di JOIN my_table pt
    ON di.id2 = pt.target
```

[image]

The red color is showing the output of the query.
I know there is nothing wrong with the routing result but when i am trying to get the geometry, 'target' value is i think the only way to get it for display

[image]

I want the result as i am showing in the 2nd image with Red color, but right now i am getting extra road segments (shown in Green color) because i am choosing to display geometry from target value.

What can I do in order to get a better result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use id3 of the result instead of id2 because id3 is the edge id according to http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/ksp/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`source` and `target` attribute contain node ID's. Each node ID should be unique, but it can appear multiple times in `source` and `target` column, because a node can be the connecting point for more than one road link.

Depending of the direction (defined by the geometry) of the road link the node ID is `source` or `target`.